# Bots on WC3 ROC and TFT?

Tags: warcraft-3

Does anyone know why so many bots have emerged on Reign of Chaos and the Frozen Throne games? It's hard to play any sort of custom map game with them spamming the threads and rooms. Furthermore they then advertise in game, both them as well as clans and it is irksome to say the least.

Comment: Are you looking for the reason why they have emerged or a solution to block/stop them?

Comment: @JamesJiao Both :)

Comment: @JamesJiao thanks for the edits, i'm kind of sleep deprived at the moment though that is no excuse

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are so many bots because now you can get a cd key for a very small price. Also Blizzards isn't as agressively banning them as before SC2 and D3.
And these bots could establish them self because they are mostly faster than the common wc3 host. Also if the bot lags, all people have the same lag and there isn't a host without lag who pwns all the others.

You can try to report bot accounts, but I'm not sure if that will help much, because they just create a new account or get a new cd key.